# React + Foundation - Render Modal with different props on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I am working off of course example "Todo" app by trying to incorporate Foundation Modal.  I have three components in question: TodoList.jsx, Todo.jsx, and TodoModal.jsx.

What I want is a link to show up below each todo in todoList to popup a modal with todo contents.  My problem: I can launch the Modal, but same Modal pops up regardless of which todo link I'm clicking.  It seems like I am not able to update the props in TodoModal.jsx and may be component lifecycle in React, but I really need help proceeding ahead.  I just took an online React course, so I am still new. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Below are TodoList.jsx (which sends todo data to TodoModal.jsx and Todo.jsx) and TodoModal.jsx.

**TodoList.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var {connect} = require('react-redux');
import Todo from 'Todo';
var TodoAPI = require('TodoAPI');

import TodoModal from 'TodoModal';

export var TodoList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      var {todos, showCompleted, searchText} = this.props;
      var renderTodos = () => {
      var filteredTodos = TodoAPI.filterTodos(todos, showCompleted, searchText);

      if (filteredTodos.length === 0) {
        return (  <p className="container__message">Nothing To Do</p>  );
      }

      return filteredTodos.map((todo) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo}/>
            <div>
              <a data-open="item-modal">
                  {todo.id}
              </a>
            <TodoModal todo={todo}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });
    };

    return (
      <div>
        {renderTodos()}
      </div>
    )
  }
});    
export default connect((state) => {return state })(TodoList);
```

**TodoModal.jsx:**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

var TodoModal = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function () {
    var modalMarkup = (
      <div id="item-modal" className="reveal tiny text-center" data-reveal="">
        <h4>{this.props.todo.text}</h4>
        <p>{this.props.todo.id}</p>
        <p>
          <button className="button hollow" data-close="">
            Okay
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    );

    var $modal = $(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(modalMarkup));
    $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).html($modal);
    var modal = new Foundation.Reveal($("#item-modal"));
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function (newProps) {
    console.log(newProps)
  },

  render: function () {  
    return (<div> </div>);
  }
});
module.exports = TodoModal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `Foundation Modal` but I believe the problem is with when you're setting up the `modalMarkup` component.

According to the lifecycle of React components, `componentDidMount` is only called **once** when the component is loaded. When you get new props via `componentWillRecieveProps`, the `componentDidMount` function is NOT re-invoked and therefore your modal is not referencing the new props.

Instead try to create the modal in both (if you can) `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` to handle the new props, maybe via a `createModal(props)` function which you can pass in the relevant set of props.

I wish I could give you more information on how to create the modal but as I said I'm not familiar with `Foundation Modal`.

You can read more about the lifecyle of the components here: [Component Specs and Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

**Updated in response to your comment**

To pass new props to your `TodoModal` component you simply need to change the value you're passing to the `TodoModal` component's `todo` property. For example lets assume you have a component called `CompA` which is rendering `CompB` and `CompB` requires a property `item`. `CompA`'s render may look like this:

**CompA**

```
render: function () {
    return (<CompB item={this.props.myItem}/>);
}
```

But now lets say that `CompB` can be provided new property values and defines the `componentWillRecieveProps` function. The current setup would ONLY pass a prop to `CompB` if `CompA`'s property `myItem` was changed. You could technically do this but you could also do something like the following:

**CompA**

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        item: this.props.myItem
    };
},

render: function() {
    // Use the state as the value for CompB's property
    // Then changing the state will invoke CompB's componentWillReceiveProps function
    return (<CompB item={this.state.item}/>);
}
```

Now in this case change `CompA`'s state will the new value to be passed to `CompB` and then `CompB` would receive it as a newly received props. You can make the state change be invoked by some event like a click, hover, whatever and you should have what you were asking about.

Comment: Thank you @Fizz!  This is helpful and on track to what I want to do.  Disregarding Foundation portion, can you elaborate on how I can send props after clicking a link to TodoModal.jsx?  I have added `componentWillReceiveProps` but I am having trouble it to receive props.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, @Fizz.  I used your suggestion, along with a "showModal" flag that I would keep track with state.